# Catfish Search in Thunar doesn't work in Xfce

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, search, thunar

The Search in Thunar file manager context menu using `catfish` is present by default as a custom action in Linux Mint Xfce:

[image]

The command used is `catfish --fileman=thunar --path=%f` (also recommended here: http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions).

But in fact it doesn't work.

Comment: bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1476358

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact a simplified form of that command works:

```
catfish --path=%f
```

In Thunar, go to Edit - Configure custom actions, and edit the Search action.

[image]

Comment: You should report this (Question and Answer) as a Bug at the [Launchpad Portal for Mint](https://launchpad.net/linuxmint) so that it can be properly scripted for all users/

Comment: @eyoung100 - bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1476358

Comment: `--path` defines a default search path and this usage is wrong! Check answer from @vdicarlo.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's over a year ago, but I just wanted to add to the answer by *cipricus*. You need to go to the tab "Appearance Conditions" (next to the "Basic" tab) and put a tick in the boxes for the file types you want. Then catfish works.

And yes, it's fast!

Regards

Answer (score 1):

While `catfish --path=%f` did not work for me, `catfish %f` did.

Comment: Thank you! This is working on Debian 10! `catfish --path=%f` did not work. Actually, in `man catfish` parameter `--path` is described as *"default search path"*. Do we want to always chabnge the default? No! We do not! Manual itself defines this usage: `catfish [options] path query` so the `path` is allready there and we should not use the `--path` parameter to change *"default search path"* but instead use the program as @vdicarlo pointed out.

Comment: I changed my mind and use it like this now: `catfish --path=~ %f`. It is nice to have a constant default search path in case anything fails.